# "Error reading data" while executing a RabbitMQ consumer in Symfony

Tags: docker, rabbitmq, symfony, php-amqplib

I have a RabbitMQ container and a PHP 7 container with a Symfony 3.1.x project that executes a RabbitMQ consumer using the [OldSoundRabbitMqBundle](https://github.com/videlalvaro/RabbitMqBundle).

When running this command that executes the `test` consumer:

```
bin/console rabbitmq:consumer -w test
```

I get the following error:

> [PhpAmqpLib\Exception\AMQPIOException]
>
> Error reading data. Received 0 instead of expected 7 bytes

My setup is very simple and I checked the following things:

- RabbitMQ is at its latest version (3.6.5)
- The configured `host`, `vhost`, `user`, `password` parameters are correct
- `mbstring` extension is enabled

It's really easy to set up a project to reproduce the issue.

The sample project is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/michaelperrin/sf-rabbitmq-test) and instructions are provided in the README file to reproduce the issue with just a few steps.

Here are some highlights:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'
services:
  php:
    build: ./docker/php/
    links:
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/rabbitmq-test
    working_dir: /var/www/rabbitmq-test

  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.6-management
```

**config.yml**

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            host:     'rabbitmq'
            port:     5672
            user:     'guest'
            password: 'guest'
            vhost:    '/'
            lazy:     false
            # ...
    producers:
        # ...
    consumers:
        test:
            connection:       default
            exchange_options: {name: 'test', type: direct}
            queue_options:    {name: 'test'}
            callback:         test_consumer
```

The `test_consumer` service is a very simple class implementing the `ConsumerInterface` interface.

Would someone have any idea concerning my problem?

Comment: This happen without any pending message?

Comment: @Yonel Yes, it happens even without any pending message. I don't see any error on the RabbitMQ side.

Comment: The exception comes from `SocketIO.php` or `StreamIO.php` ?

Comment: What do you do in `test_consumer` ?

Comment: @Yonel The exception comes from `SocketIO.php`.

Comment: @Yonel `test_consumer` does nothing. Just to check if there would be any errors, I made it log a message with the `logger` service. And I can see that the consumer **is** run without any issue (my log entry does appear in the logs file).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123961/discussion-between-yonel-and-michael-perrin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was really straightforward. I had to change this in my `config.yml`:

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            # ...

            use_socket: true
```

to:

```
old_sound_rabbit_mq:
    connections:
        default:
            # ...

            use_socket: false
```

Note that `false` is the default value.

Comment: Great! from this parameter depends the connection factory class used for new connections (+1)

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks for your help @Yonel .

Comment: Works like a charm without socket!, but how can make it working with sockets ? I already installed sockets extension for php but even did not work.